# Trying to understand DLL returns for String types

Tags: string, vba, dll

I'm trying to get some insight on string handling with DLLs.  I'm not sure I understand the difference in the different string data structures and how to handle each or how to identify which is being used.

I have the following code to demonstrate my dilemma.

```
Declare Function SCardListReaders Lib "winscard.dll" Alias "SCardListReadersA" ( _
    ByVal phContext As Integer, _
    ByVal mszGroups As String, _
    ByVal mszReaders As String, _
    ByRef pcchReaders As Integer _
    ) As Integer

Sub GetReaders()

Dim RetVal As Integer
Dim Readers As String
Dim ReadersStrLength As Integer

Debug.Print "GetReaders"
RetVal = SCardListReaders(0, "", Readers, ReadersStrLength)
Debug.Print "Returns = " & RetVal & ", Readers = " & Chr(34) & Readers & Chr(34) & _
            " Length = " & ReadersStrLength

RetVal = SCardListReaders(0, "", Readers, ReadersStrLength)
Debug.Print "Returns = " & RetVal & ", Readers = " & Chr(34) & Readers & Chr(34) & _
            " Length = " & ReadersStrLength

End Sub
Sub GetReaders2()

Dim RetVal As Integer
Dim Readers As String * 50
Dim ReadersStrLength As Integer

Debug.Print "GetReaders2"
RetVal = SCardListReaders(0, "", Readers, ReadersStrLength)
Debug.Print "Returns = " & RetVal & ", Readers = " & Chr(34) & Readers & Chr(34) & _
            " Length = " & ReadersStrLength

RetVal = SCardListReaders(0, "", Readers, ReadersStrLength)
Debug.Print "Returns = " & RetVal & ", Readers = " & Chr(34) & Readers & Chr(34) & _
            " Length = " & ReadersStrLength

End Sub
```

Which returns the following:

```
GetReaders
Returns = 0, Readers = "" Length = 23
Returns = 0, Readers = "" Length = 23

GetReaders2
Returns = 0, Readers = "                                                  " Length = 23
Returns = 0, Readers = "Athena ASEDrive V3C 0                             " Length = 23
```

The documentation for the function is found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379793(v=vs.85).aspx which indicates that the return for the mszReaders is a multi-string.  So, I'm thinking the missing data is actually being delivered I just don't know how to access it.

I can make the second instantiation of the routine work for my purposes I just doesn't seem reasonable to do it that way.  What am I missing?  I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the sample code from documentation that you linked:

> ```
> case SCARD_S_SUCCESS:
>     // Do something with the multi string of readers.
>     // Output the values.
>     // A double-null terminates the list of values.
>     pReader = pmszReaders;
>     while ( '\0' != *pReader )
>     {
>         // Display the value.
>         printf("Reader: %S\n", pReader );
>         // Advance to the next value.
>         pReader = pReader + wcslen((wchar_t *)pReader) + 1;
>     }
> ```

Your passed `String` is being filled with a null *delimited* array of strings, terminated with a double null.  When you pass it an empty variable length `String`, it's being marshalled as only the first item because it interprets the first null that it encounters as the end of the string.

---

Again, from the documentation that you linked:

> mszReaders [out]
>
> Multi-string that lists the card readers within the supplied reader
>   groups. If this value is NULL, SCardListReaders ignores the buffer
>   length supplied in pcchReaders, writes the length of the buffer that
>   would have been returned if this parameter had not been NULL to
>   pcchReaders, and returns a success code.

This API follows a double-call usage pattern - the first call provides the required buffer size and the second call is used to write to the buffer. If you're responsible for providing the buffer, you have to pass it a pointer to an existing `String`.

---

This leads to your other issue - your function declaration is wrong. Again, from your linked documentation:

> ```
> LONG WINAPI SCardListReaders(
>   _In_     SCARDCONTEXT hContext,
>   _In_opt_ LPCTSTR      mszGroups,
>   _Out_    LPTSTR       mszReaders,
>   _Inout_  LPDWORD      pcchReaders
> );
> ```

First, it returns a `Long`, not an `Integer`. The `h` prefix on `hContext` stands for "handle", which is also a pointer, so you shouldn't be passing that as an `Integer` ***either***.  The correct declaration for the function is:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function SCardListReaders Lib "winscard.dll" Alias "SCardListReadersA" ( _
    ByVal phContext As LongPtr, _
    ByVal mszGroups As LongPtr, _
    ByVal mszReaders As LongPtr, _
    ByRef pcchReaders As Long _
    ) As Long
```

Based on your code, you're using the NULL `mszGroups` calling convention, so your calling code should look more like this:

```
Sub GetReaders()
    Const SCARD_S_SUCCESS As Long = 0
    Dim result As Long
    Dim readers As String
    Dim bufferSize As Long

    'Request the buffer size.
    result = SCardListReaders(0, 0, 0, bufferSize)
    'Test your return value for success.
    If result <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS Then
        Debug.Print "Buffer sizing call failed with return of " & result
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Size your output buffer
    readers = String$(bufferSize, Chr$(0))
    'Make the second call to fill the buffer.
    result = SCardListReaders(0, 0, StrPtr(readers), bufferSize)
    'Test the return value of *that* call too.
    If result <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS Then
        Debug.Print "Buffer fill call failed with return of " & result
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Process the null-delimited array.
    Dim readerArray() As String
    readerArray = Split(readers, Chr$(0))
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(readerArray) To UBound(readerArray)
        Debug.Print readerArray(index)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note this is untested (I don't have any readers to validate it with), but it should at very least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! How to dynamically size the string and splitting it is what I was missing. I kinda fell into the double call pattern but was unsure of it. BTW your code works if I define **mszReaders As String**; If set to **Long** it returns gibberish.

Comment: @M.Haas - Glad you got it working.  I'm guessing that passing the string instead of a pointer is an ascii\unicode conversion issue.  The signature above would probably work with the unicode version of the function.